# Vim specify syntax file (not syntax type)?

Tags: c, vim, syntax-highlighting

Hi looking to be able to do something like:

```
vim syntaxfile=custom_c.vim
```

I do not want to set a syntax type, I want to specify a syntax file by pathname.

Please assist / give pointers.

Willing to write c code to achieve this.

Comment: "Syntax" files are nothing special. This is simply VimScript.

Comment: Do you want *only* this syntax file, or this in addition to the default C syntax files? Generally (I think) it’s possible to clear the syntax and start over anyway

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you use:

```
set syntax=custom_c
```

This will then look for a file called `custom_c.vim` in one of the syntax paths.

i.e.

```
~/.vim/syntax/custom_c.vim
```

Or

```
~/.vim/after/syntax/custom_c.vim
```

[The answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10815/27444) is really good, and goes into more details generally.

Somewhere to look in the help system would be:

```
:help mysyntaxfile
```

To automate you could use an autogroup to detect if file is in a given path and set the `syntax=` setting accordingly.